# Cannot install Samba on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: samba, bind

I am stuck on this for almost 2 days now and have tried everything I can.

I have a bitnami Gitlab Virtual machine up and running. There is a need to install winbind on this machine and since winbind has a dependency on samba, I have to install Samba on this machine.

Installing Samba gives me the below error message:

```
Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ububntu0.14.04.4) ...
mkdir -p /home/git/.ssh: OK
chmod 700 /home/git/.ssh: OK
mkdir -p -d: mkdir: invalid option -- 'd'
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information
Failed 
/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/install failed
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
samba
```

Regards

Comment: mkdir has no -d option. Try to install Samba from another source, i.e. https://launchpad.net/~bo-vircio/+archive/ubuntu/samba or https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=samba

Comment: @Smile4ever: Why? What's wrong with the version in Canonical's package repositories?

Comment: Uhm, why does Apt use this non-standard `install` program at `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/install`? What's the output of `echo "$PATH"`, `which -a install`, and `/opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/install --version`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster it calls mkdir -p -d. The option -d does not exist in mkdir, so I think installing this samba package won't work. I don't know what the -d option is supposed to do.

Comment: @Smile4ever: `mkdir` is likely invoked by `install` so I'm trying to look at that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: which -a install returns /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/install and version of the same is 8.21

Comment: @Smile4ever: I tried your suggestion however it is not working